# atbegshi warnings printed as part of output

Tags: warnings, atbegshi, shipout

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,atbegshi}
\usepackage[2-]{pagesel}% Ignore first page
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

The output includes a warning from [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi):

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will happen after every discarded page.

[`pagesel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel) discards pages depending on the inclusion criteria you specify. When a page is excluded, the shipout box is voided, which confuses [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi).

To avoid this, switch the load order, loading `atbegshi` *after* `pagesel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[2-]{pagesel}
\usepackage{lipsum,atbegshi}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Additions to Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219256/16967).

Also package `atbegshi` has a "page discard" feature.
For example, the first page can be ignored by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,atbegshi}
% \usepackage[2-]{pagesel}% Ignore first page
\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Or ignoring all even pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
  \else
    \AtBeginShipoutDiscard
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Of course, the syntax is not as comfortable as with package `pagesel`, thus Werner's solution with using `pagesel` before `atbegshi` is the easiest way.

Nevertheless, the ignoring via `atbegshi` allows funnier things, like ignoring
pages, which are marked by a reference:

```
% \nofiles % for the final run
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,atbegshi, refcount}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifnum\getrefbykeydefault{IgnoreThisPage}{page}{-\maxdimen}=\value{page}%
    \AtBeginShipoutDiscard
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\section{This page is ignored}
\label{IgnoreThisPage}
\lipsum[26-50]
\end{document}
```

In the first run the reference is written to the `.aux` file. In the second run the page with the reference is then discarded. Since the page is not output, the reference does not get written to the `.aux` file and a third run writes the reference again, but includes the page. Therefore the run, which excludes files should call `\nofiles` to prevent changes to the auxiliary files.