# How to prevent shipout of selected pages AND get a full set of cross-references

Tags: auxiliary-files, atbegshi, shipout

I would like to retain only a subset of pages, i.e. those which have been marked with the tag command  `\keepthispage` and have come up with the following preamble commands.

```
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{keeppage}
\boolfalse{keeppage}
\AtBeginShipout{%
\ifbool{keeppage}
    {\global\boolfalse{keeppage}}
    {\global\boolfalse{keeppage}\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\newcommand{\keepthispage}{\global\booltrue{keeppage}}
```

This works nicely except that also all labels on pages not included in the output are not written to the aux file, and therefore I end up with a lot of missing references. As explained by Heiko Oberdiek in [reply to a different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219271/38437), it is first necessary to process the complete file without page suppression, e.g. by adding `\renewcommand{\keepthispage}{}` and commenting out the `\AtBeginShipout` command below the above snippet, and then rerun it by using `\nofiles`.

However, this requires editing the file between runs. Is there a way to achieve this outcome by running latex/pdflatex twice on the same input file without requiring editing of the file in between (automated editing such as use of `sed` also does not count as the .tex file in question is autogenerated, and the user expects that he can just run it through latex - instead latex should detect if it is in the first or second pass, and behave appropriately).

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) at all? What about *page* references via `\pageref`?

Comment: ...and what is `DIFkeeppage`? Come to think of it, you should just create a complete document that we can compile and replicate your current problem rather than having to create our own. It's just the right thing to do. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Werner I simplified a slightly more complicated use case in constructing the code snippet, and the DIFkeeppage is a transcription error I made in doing this. I see in your answer you guessed correctly what I meant, and I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page references are the only thing that are influenced by this delayed writing to the `.aux` - it's a requirement in order to obtain the correct reference. However, if you're not using any page reference, you can avoid this delayed `.aux`-writing by using an "immediate writing wrapper" ([`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) provides this via `\zref@immediate@wrapper`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,zref}
\usepackage{atbegshi,etoolbox}

\newbool{keeppage}
\boolfalse{keeppage}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifbool{keeppage}
      {\global\boolfalse{keeppage}}% Keep this page
      {\global\boolfalse{keeppage}\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}% Discard this page
\newcommand{\keepthispage}{\global\booltrue{keeppage}}

\makeatletter
\let\oldlabel\label% Store \label
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{% Update \label to write to the .aux immediately
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{\oldlabel{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See Section~\ref{sec:second}.\keepthispage% Keep this page

\section{First section}\label{sec:first}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{First subsection}\label{subsec:first.first}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{Second subsection}\label{subsec:first.second}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{Last subsection}\label{subsec:first.last}\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Second section}\label{sec:second}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{First subsection}\label{subsec:second.first}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{Second subsection}\label{subsec:second.second}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{Last subsection}\label{subsec:second.last}\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file will now contain all the correct *counter* references, but an incorrect page reference:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\zref@newlabel[2]{}
\newlabel{sec:first}{{1}{\thepage }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}First section}{1}}
\newlabel{subsec:first.first}{{1.1}{\thepage }}
\newlabel{subsec:first.second}{{1.2}{\thepage }}
\newlabel{subsec:first.last}{{1.3}{\thepage }}
\newlabel{sec:second}{{2}{\thepage }}
\newlabel{subsec:second.first}{{2.1}{\thepage }}
\newlabel{subsec:second.second}{{2.2}{\thepage }}
\newlabel{subsec:second.last}{{2.3}{\thepage }}
```

Note that the ToC-writing still occurs at page shipout (and is therefore lost for pages not kept).

Comment: If you know the pages to be shipped out, a two-stage compilation with [`pagesel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel) is also an option.

Comment: Works well and this should deal with nearly all use cases (ultimately this is to become a highlighting style in latexdiff script, so it depends ultimately on the users of that script)